# SuggestBox color the items

Tags: gwt, colors, suggestbox

I want to give the items in my suggestbox a custom background color.
Is this possible?

like

```
item.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");
```

Comment: Have a look at `DefaultSuggestionDisplay` to see all CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your css file to change the background color of an item/selected-item

```
.gwt-SuggestBoxPopup .item {
    background: red !important;
}
.gwt-SuggestBoxPopup .item-selected {
    background: black !important;
}
```

look [**here**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_suggestionbox_widget.htm) for detailed information